# Merge Sort isn't sorting

Tags: java, mergesort

Could someone please help debug the logic flaw? The following is a class variable:
int[] arr = {6,5,7,2,3};

The array basically remains unsorted. There are no errors though.

```
public static void mergeSort(int left, int right){
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    Comparable[] temp = new Comparable[arr.length];
    //Integer[] integerArr = CodeCheck.intToIntegerArr(arr);
    mergeSort(temp, 0, arr.length-1);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
}
public static void mergeSort(Comparable[] temp, int left, int right) {
    if (left<right) {
        int leftEnd=(left+right)/2;
        mergeSort(temp,left,leftEnd);
        mergeSort(temp,leftEnd+1,right);
        merge(temp,left,leftEnd,right);
    }
}

public static void merge(Comparable[] temp, int left, int leftEnd, int right){
    int rightEnd=leftEnd+1;
    int k=0;
    while(left<=leftEnd && right<=rightEnd) {
        if (arr[left]<=arr[right]) {temp[k++]=arr[left++];}
        else {temp[k++]=arr[right++];}
        //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(temp));
    }
    while(left<=leftEnd) {
        temp[k++]=arr[left++];
    }
    while(right<=rightEnd) {
        temp[k++]=arr[right++];
    }
    int num=left-right+1;
    for(int i=0;i<num;++i,rightEnd--){
        arr[rightEnd]=(int) temp[rightEnd];
    }
}
```

Comment: Attach a debugger to it and step through.

Comment: while(left<=leftEnd) {  should be   while(left>=leftEnd) {  ?

Comment: found the bug, int k=left;